# How can I make bazel use external storage when building?

Tags: linux, bazel

When building certain code with bazel I'm running out of storage space. I'd like bazel to store its things on a USB drive instead of in my `~/.cache` folder. How can I tell bazel to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`--output_user_root`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--output_user_root) flag.

Example:

```
bazel --output_user_root=/path/to/directory build //foo:bar
```

Comment: When trying this solution on an AWS instance, I met the warning like 
    WARNING: Output base 
    '/workspace/bazel/.cache/0d1ff2dcdcd5fe715305037694b909f9' is on NFS. This may lead to surprising failures and undetermined behavior.

Comment: eh, the link now returns 404 page not found :(

Answer (score 6):

You can change the outputRoot directory by changing the `$TEST_TMPDIR` variable.

```
export TEST_TMPDIR=/path/to/directory
```

---

From [the bazel docs](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/output_directories.html):

> The *outputRoot* directory is `~/.cache/bazel`. (Unless $TEST_TMPDIR is set, as in a test of bazel itself, in which case this directory is used instead.)

Comment: Setting TEST_TMPDIR makes Bazel believe it's running inside of a test and will heavily limit its resource use, slowing down builds.

Comment: god bless you Matt!

Answer (score 4):

I symlinked `~/.cache/bazel` to a directory on my other drive. Looks to be working so far. i.e.

```
ln -s /mnt/otherdrive/bazel_cache ~/.cache/bazel
```

I thought to move the old cache to avoid rebuilding, but I noticed symlinks to directories within the cache and didn't want to deal with transferring those so they pointed to the new directory as well. So I just deleted the old cache, symlinked, and rebuilt.